# Which is the voltage on this capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

I can't figure out the voltage on this 50uF capacitor. There are three values on it 420 V~ , 470V~, and 250VAC. Can someone tell me which it is? Thanks!!

[image: Capacitor]

Comment: It has different ratings for reliability, so consider it 50 uF 250Vac 60 Hz /50Hz

Comment: Could it be used as a 50 uf 450 VAC cap? Or will that cause overheating and issues with the motor?

Comment: higher voltages accelerate failure rate or MTBF  from a Class A to B 10kh or class C 3kh

Comment: I'll be using it for a short time until i can get the right specs. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: 3k to 10k hours is still a long time. It might be cheaper to get a spare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of them, of course.

It meets the European EN60252-1 "class C" standard (meant to indicate no significant degradation within 3,000 hours of run time) if you run it at less than 470 volts.

It meets the EN60252-1 "class B" standard (10,000 hours) if you run it at less than 420 volts.

It meets some other standard (possibly EIA-456-A, which is meant to test a 60,000 hour lifetime) if you run it at less than 250 volts.

Since it shows a 470V rating, operating it at 450 should be fine, but it will probably have a much shorter useful lifetime than it would in a lower-voltage application.

Comment: It'll be used for a short time until the local electronics store restocks what I need. Thank you for clearing it up!!

Comment: "250V AC" clearly refers to 250V rms. Is it possible the 420/470V ratings refer to peak voltages for compatibility with the DC ratings preferred on most other capacitors? (In which case, 450V RMS might be problematic)